# Should my shared entities be versioned separately from my webapps?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jpa, project-management

We have 4 webapps that run on the same server and communicate with the same database. They use JPA annotated classes to communicate with the database. They also will be on separate repositories so they can be versioned independent of each other.

Each webapp has a MVC architecture, where portions of the model are the same amongst the webapps. We can choose to violate DRY and repeat the shared parts of the model for each webapp, or we can introduce a coupling to the shared portions of the model by versioning the model itself.

What is the best way to address this issue? What do we do if the database schema needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this

```
they also will be on separate repositories so they can be versioned independent of each other.
```

or this

```
We can choose to violate DRY and repeat the shared parts of the model for each webapp
```

I would use one shared model between the different webapps and have them included in each project using maven as a dependency manager.

Actually, how can are you using different versions (of entity classes) when all apps depend on the same database ?

Comment: We have one app that deals with user location tracking while another app deals with user profile management. Both (for example) would require access to a first_name and last_name column in the user row of the database. We're investigating the feasibility of keeping both webapps in different repositories so a new version of one doesn't require a new version of the other. Currently all 4 webapps bump up one version when only one has changes b/c they're in the same repo with a shared model (using maven).